# how to minimize ipa size?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipa

I have created archive file.

1. Right click on it and select show in finder and
2. Select myapp.xarchinve right click on it select
3. Show content application and then
4. Got to application folder and
5. Select myapp.app and right click on it and
6. Select myapp exicutable file.

It shows size 19 mb I want to minimize this size but I don't know why it shows that much size.

Appreciate for help

Comment: iOS will use memory for cache. My app has 50MB and sometimes will go up to 70, and all of the sudden will be back at 50MB.

Answer (score 0):

19MB is not that much, it's not at all certain you can get it much smaller.

That said, in `Build Settings` of your project, do a search for `strip` and check that the linked project is being stripped

(you could also strip the debug symbols, but then crash logs will have little to no info in them)

Comment: but I have same application for android which size is 6mb so I want to check why ipa size that much

Answer (score 0):

- Do you have any sound files that can be large?
- Do you have any extern frameworks included? **(These are most likely to increase space so much and you can't do anything about it for now..until iOS 9 will appear)**
- Do you have any high-quality and large images?
- Check your Bundle to see what files you have there that can increase your space by that much

I don't know what your app does but 19mb is not very much in my opinion.